# Managing rubies with rvm but rbenv replying with ruby version not installed

Tags: ruby, rvm, rbenv

I used to use rbenv to manage ruby versions. I uninstalled it because I had to switch to rvm to install an old version of ruby. Now in my project, if I do `ruby -v` I get `ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]` but when I try to create my database with `bundle exec rails db:create` I get `rbenv: version '2.3.1' is not installed`. Can someone help me with that ?

Comment: Looks like you didn't uninstall it fully. Look for the remnants in `.profile` (or similar files for your shell)

Comment: I myself haven't used rbenv. Are you saying it can't install older rubies (such as 2.3.1)?

Comment: One old ruby version (I think 2.3.0) couldn't be installed with rbenv

Comment: rbenv is not properly uninstalled from your machine which is why rbenv is still looking for ruby 2.3.1 version. Uninstall rbenv fully from your machine. 

Also, please provide some more details like what OS you are using. What issue you were facing to uninstall older version of ruby with rbenv. I just installed 2.3.0 with rbenv on my machine (to see if I get any error) and it successfully installed it. 

I would suggest you to stick to rbenv and try fixing the issue you are facing.